Problem finding periodic points and saddle points
Consider the diffeomorphiosm $Q_\lambda$ of the plane given by
\begin{equation}
    Q_\lambda\begin{pmatrix}
        x_1\\ y_1
    \end{pmatrix}=\begin{cases}
        e^x-\lambda\\
        -\frac\lambda2\arctan y
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
where $\lambda$ is a parameter.
a) Find all fixed points and periodic points of period 2 for $Q_\lambda.
Find the fixed points.
Solve $Q_\lambda=0$:
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        &e^x-\lambda=0 \implies x=\ln{\lambda} \\
        &-\frac\lambda2\arctan y=0 \implies y=0
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
The fixed point is at $(x,y)=(\ln{\lambda},0)$.
Find the periodic points:
Solve $Q_\lambda=\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}$
Consider for $\lambda=0$
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        &e^x=x \implies x=\ln{x} \\
        &0=y
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
which has periodic point for $y=0$, but none for x variable.
for $\lambda<0$:
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        &e^x-\lambda=x \implies x=\lambda-W_n(-e^\lambda) \implies x=0 \ \text{when} \ \lambda=-1\\
         &-\frac\lambda2\arctan y=y \implies y=\tan{-\frac{2y}{\lambda}}\implies y=\tan{2y}
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
We have a consistent periodic point for $\lambda=-1$, being $p=(0,0)$.
Classify each of these points as sinks, sources or saddles.
Compute the Jacobian:
\begin{equation}
    DQ_\lambda\begin{pmatrix}
        x_1\\ y_1
    \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
        e^x& 0 \\
        0 & -\frac\lambda2\frac{1}{y^2+1}
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
Insert for $(x,y)=(\ln{\lambda},0)$ and obtain that $\text{Det}(DQ_\lambda)=-\lambda\frac{\lambda}{2}$, and with $\lambda=-1$ we have  $\text{Det}(DQ_\lambda)=-\frac12<0$. That is a sink.
that $\text{Det}(DQ_\lambda)=-\frac{\lambda}{2}$, and with $\lambda=-1$ we have  $\text{Det}(DQ_\lambda)=\frac12>0$. That is a sink.
But is this really all, the exercise has a third question saying "If the point is a saddle identify and sketch the stable and unstable manifolds"?
It would mean that something is not correct in this solution. Any comments appreciated.
Thanks

You have a sink if both eigenvalues are negative, a source if both eigenvalues are positive, and a saddle-point if one eigenvalue is positive and the other is negative.
